Programatically send data to bash stdin
I want to programatically change user input in shell, similar to how complete shell built in achieves this.
So whenver you press TAB unix systems complete built-in appends some data to your input. I want to achieve similar effect, to already running shell.
Most of the methods I tried simply display characters in the terminal, but they cannot be interpretted as commands.
echo "New input" > /proc/<bashID>/fd/0 - doesn't work, only writes "New input" in the terminal, it cannot be edited or interpreted as command.

There's no easy way to do this. If the terminal is a pty, as it usually is in a window or SSH server, you would have to write the data to the master end of the pty. The complete built-in doesn't send the input to stdin, it puts it in the shell's editing buffer (it can do this because it's built into the shell).

Only ways I could think about (assuming you are using a graphical env) :
if using xterm, make use of  xterm*VT100.Translations (X11 resources)
else use a test automation tool, like xdotool, to mimic user interactions, key typing

Does this answer your question? Get autocompletion when invoking a "read" inside a Bash script
